# Call all values of function members in Python inside Class function without creating a object

Tags: python, class, instance

I'm trying to create a class

```
 class DataBase():
        #column declaration
        name = 'my_name' 
        id = '42'
```

representing a Database containing a function create_db() in which you can create the database with all the member variables of the class as columns.

For better overview I'm not intending to just change the values inside the function but rather to have them all stored as class members and extend them at will.

```
def create_db(self):
        members = dir(DataBase())
```

This is what I've tried so far. Unfortunately it won't return the values but only the member names themselves.

Another hurdle is that I'm trying to use the class as an object it self instead of creating one to keep it simple and clean.

Comment: `getattr(self, member)` ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#getattr

Comment: You seem to be trying to implement an ORM from scratch. Why not use an existing one?